# Connecting/importing PostGIS database in ArcGIS Desktop via localhost?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, file-geodatabase

I want to import PostgreSQL database in PostGIS to ArcGIS Desktop?

Is it required to install ArcSDE?

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have several questions lurking in this one Question. Esri introduced [Query Layers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/what-is-a-query-layer-.htm) at ArcGIS 10.1, which allow Desktop and Server to access geodata tables using native geometry without requiring installation of an enterprise geodatabase (there hasn't been an "SDE" product in a *long* time, and 10.3 eliminated the ArcSDE application server, so only the Database Connection component remains). It is still necessary to enable an enterprise geodatabase to obtain versioned editing and geodatabase functionality, but it isn't necessary for *access* to PostGIS geometry/geography columns (provided that the database components are compatible with the Esri release,  of course)

You've stated you want to "import" the data. This implies transfer, not use in place. Whether Query Layers will meet your needs depends on where you want to transfer the data. You can certainly export data from a supported Query Layer to any file/personal/enterprise geodatabase or shapefile; other formats may also be possible.

Older versions of ArcGIS supported database access through installation of appropriate client libraries, but by the time 10.3 was released, Esri had incorporated a component known as Data Store, which is based on PostgreSQL, so PG 9.3 libraries are included in the base ArcGIS 10.3 Desktop / Server installs.

I would strongly urge you to upgrade both your Desktop (to 10.4.1 or 10.5.1) and PostgreSQL (to 9.4 or 9.5, with PostGIS 2.2)., since 10.4 and beyond support *both read and write* of PostgreSQL database tables without enterprise-enabling the PG  database, and 9.1 is an extremely old version of PostgreSQL.